# Percent of Group, not total

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

It seems like there are a lot of answers out there but I can't seem to relate it to my specific issue.  I want to get the breakdown of yes/no for the specific Group.  Not get the percent of the yes for the entire population of data.

I have tried the following code in the "What I'm Getting" % of Total cell =

*=FormatPercent(Count(Fields!SessionID.Value)/Count((Fields!SessionID.Value), "Tablix1"),)*

=FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Value.Value)/Count((Fields!SessionID.Value), "Value"),)

[image]

Comment: What I'm looking to do is provide the yes/no ratio for each group.  So the sum of group A (9) divided by the Yes total (1) = 11.11%   1/9=11    And so on for each group.  Each person within those groups wants to be able to see these ratios.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in SSRS.  Excel no problem....but ssrs...no bueno   oh and group C and D are wrong...Updating with a new pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be a case of changing the Scope in your expression to make sure the denominator is the total for the group, not the entire Dataset or Tablix, i.e. something like:

```
=Count(Fields!SessionID.Value) / Count(Fields!SessionID.Value, "MyGroup")
```

Where `MyGroup` is the name of the group, i.e. something like:

[image]

If this is still not clear, your best option would be to add a few sample rows, and your desired result for these, to the question so we can replicate your exact issue.

**Edit after more info added**

Thanks for adding more details. I have created a Dataset based on your example:

[image]

[image]

And I've created a table based on this:

[image]

The group is based on the `Group` field:

[image]

The Group % expression is:

```
=Fields!YesNoCount.Value / Sum(Fields!YesNoCount.Value, "MyGroup")
```

This is taking the `YesNoCount` value of each row and comparing it to the total `YesNoCount` value in that particular group (i.e. the `MyGroup` scope).

Note that I'm using `Sum` here, not `Count` as in your example expression - that seems to be the appropriate aggregate for your data and the required value.

Results look OK to me:

[image]

Comment: I did try that and I got the 100%    **=FormatPercent(Count(Fields!SessionID.Value)/Count((Fields!SessionID.Value), "Value"),)**                    the field isn't a grouping.  I'm trying to divide the count column.

Comment: If you can provide a few rows in a sample dataset, plus your desired results, that will give you the best chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I added something for you

Comment: I must be as dense as Chesapeake bay fog in autumn because that doesn't work for me.  I keep getting 100%  It's not dividing against the total of that group =Count(Fields!Value.Value)/Count(Fields!Value.Value,"Value")

Comment: And I am as dense as fog.  I really, REALLY appreciate your assistance and helping me through this.  I had it grouped on the wrong darn grouping.  I wasn't grouping up a level high enough.  =Count(Fields!Value.Value)/Count(Fields!Value.Value,"GroupABCD")

Comment: Don't worry, it's always obvious after you figured it out. Glad I could help.